# Where is bash installed by brew?

Tags: bash, homebrew, monterey

I just started using Mac OS Monterey and trying to install bash 5.

[image]

Previously with Intel chip Macbook, I did below.

```
brew install bash
echo '/usr/local/bin/bash' | sudo tee -a /etc/shells;
```

Did the same but there is no `/usr/local/bin/bash` anymore after `brew install bash`.

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/bash
bash: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Where is it now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brew has changed the installation location for Apple Silicon (M1/M2) to be `/opt/homebrew/bin`, see https://docs.brew.sh/Installation.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add that in general, you can find what files were installed by running `brew ls`

```
> brew ls bash
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/bin/bash
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/bin/bashbug
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/include/bash/ (59 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/lib/bash/ (39 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/lib/pkgconfig/bash.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/share/doc/ (10 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/share/info/bash.info
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/share/locale/ (39 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/share/man/ (2 files)
```